# How to prevent debug code while sending an email using Java?

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-mail

I am using a java program which sends an email to the addresses specified. The program works fine but it produces a lot of debug code in my console which is not needed. The statements that are producing the debug code are:

```
-------
 Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProperties, auth);
---
 transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
----
  transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

Is there any way to prevent this? Btw, I am using mail.jar and activation.jar for sending the email.

Sample Debug Code:

```
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOW
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using setDebug(true) in your program?

Comment: No. I am not using setDebug(true) but I would like to know if I can do setDebug(false) so that the debug code would not show up. If yes, how??

Thanks for the reply, Btw. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  [JavaMail API docs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/)

> public void setDebug(boolean debug)
>
> Set the debug setting for this Session.
>
> Since the debug setting can be turned on only after the Session has
>   been created, to turn on debugging in the Session constructor, set the
>   property mail.debug in the Properties object passed in to the
>   constructor to true. The value of the mail.debug property is used to
>   initialize the per-Session debugging flag. Subsequent calls to the
>   setDebug method manipulate the per-Session debugging flag and have no
>   affect on the mail.debug property.
>
> Parameters:
>       debug - Debug setting

Comment: You are awesome... I found where I was setting the 'mail.debug' property to true.. Changing it to false solved the problem...

Thanks a lot!